# Is there any way to receive something that indicates a NO asynchronous insert was made or return the number of rows affected in Realm for Android?

Tags: java, android, realm

I am using in realm, with java on android:

To make an insert I use: `realm.beginTransaction ();`

I need 'realm' to return me the number of rows affected. But I don't want to use "realm.copy...." as much as possible.

Comment: This is an unclear question and we don't know what platform you're using.

Comment: You should count the number of affected rows yourself, because Realm won't tell you.